# Way to iterate through python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For simplicity say I have three dictionaries that look like this:

```
first={'aaa':1,'aba':2,'acc':3}
second={'aaa':1,'aba':2,'aab':3}
output={}
```

I want to iterate/search through the keys to find and retain keys that closely match only if there is a single other closely matching key and then put them into an output dictionary. And I am using Levenstein distance to calculate string similarity and for an example let's say for this case i want strings that only differ by a single change.

So filtering the `first` dictionary, `'aaa'` and `'aba'` match within one change while `'acc'` is two changes different. Because two and only two keys match, the output should look like this: `output={'aaa':1,'aba':2}`

Filtering the `second` dictionary, there are three matches all within a levenshtein distance of 1. So nothing should be output: `output={}`

My approach was to match keys and then delete them from the dictionary, but  I cannot get this to work because i couldn't figure out a way to not look multiple times through the dictionary.

Comment: How did your dictionaries become dataframes?

Comment: Side-note: `dict` is not a good "fuzzy matching" structure; if you don't have exact matches, you'll end up doing linear search anyway, so you're not getting much of anything from using `dict`s.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  i am using levenstein distance to compute this. So I can just do `distance('aaa','aab')==1` or something similar.

Comment: Can you clear up your logic a bit more? You say the output from "filtering" `first` should be `{'aaa':1,'aba':2}` because "two and only two keys match." But output from filtering `second` should be an empty `dict` because there are **three** matches within a distance of 1? What's the distinction, here? Why aren't you looking to keep all three in `second` if they seem to satisfy the same criterion as the output for `first`?

Comment: @not_a_robot The logic is more complex than is illustrated here. But I only want to keep those keys that are only a pair of closely matching keys. If there are multiple matches they should all be discarded.

Comment: @TheNightman: Right. But you can't use it for the one major benefit of `dict`, `O(1)` lookup. If you have `'aaa'`, you can't determine the fuzzy Levenstein matches in `second` without iterating `second` exhaustively (`O(n)`). Like I said, just a side-note; by using `dict`, you lose ordering while gaining very little (the ability to find the non-fuzzy matches). You remove the ability to use more clever search strategies that might scale better for huge inputs (silly example: Using bisect on sorted `list` to find the 26 smaller ranges that could conceivably have Levenstein distances of 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from Levenshtein import distance
from itertools import permutations, combinations

def distance1(dic):
    output = {key1: dic[key1] for key1, key2 in
              permutations(dic, 2)
              if distance(key1, key2) == 1}
    if len(output) == 2:
        return output
    else:
        return {}
```

It's not very efficient since `permutations` will do duplicate work. Here's a better way to do it:

```
def distance1_better(dic):
    output = [(key1, key2) for key1, key2 in
              combinations(dic, 2)
              if distance(key1, key2) == 1]

    if len(output) == 1:
        key1, key2 = output[0]
        return {key1: dic[key1], key2: dic[key2]}
    else:
        return {}
```

Comment: Side-note: No need to call `.keys()`; `dict`s are already iterables of their keys. On Py2, calling `.keys()` involves additional unnecessary temporary `list`s, on Py3 it just involves creating a pointless keys view wrapper object. The only real reason to use `.keys()` on Py3 is if you want to use the `set`-like behaviors of keys views.

Comment: That's correct @ShadowRanger, thanks for pointing it out. Updated my answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks, this is pretty close to what I am looking for. The only problem is that this seems to work only if there is a single matching pair and not multiple matching pairs ie: `first={'aaa':1,'aba':2,'acc':3, 'ddd':1,'dde':2,'fff':3}`. Is there a good way to accomodate for this?

Comment: @TheNightman: Well, I didn't post this answer, but the solution would be to remove the test for a single output and then make a `dict` of all outputs. It would be necessary to determine what you're supposed to do when the values conflict though; in your example, all the matches have the same values, so a single key/value pairing can be done. What should happen if you have `{'aaa': 1}` in one input and `{'aaa': 2}` in another?

Comment: @ShadowRanger good idea i just tried this and i think it is working properly. Thanks.